# How to split text between different delimiters while keeping delimiters in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Is it possible to split text with different delimiters while keeping delimiters in place in returned array.

In example if I have a text that consist of : 
`sin({$=i$}^2`

and I want to split it in an array that looks like this :

`['sin(' , '{$=i$}', '^2']`

while my delimiters are `{` and `}`. What I managed to achieve is an array that looks like this : `['sin(' , '{$=i$', '}^2']`

but I can't make that last one delimiter `}` in right place with this piece of code :

```
String text = "sin({$=i$}^2";
String[] splitted = text.split("(?=[{}])");
```

Comment: How do you define "in right place"?

Comment: Match [`({[^{}]*}|[^{}]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/wN2hL8/1)

Comment: i want delimiters to be wrapped from both side of text, like `{$=i$}` or `{$FOR 0 1 1$}` so that last one delimiter `}` is at the end of that text. @FrankPuffer

Comment: not working..., throws PatternSyntaxException on first character @Tushar

Comment: @str1k3r: So you always have an opening and a closing delimiter, not symmetric delimiters like "|"?

Comment: @FrankPuffer problem solved with with bottom answer, but thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example it looks like you may be looking for

```
split("(?<=\\})|(?=\\{)")
```

We are using [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms to

- `(?<=\\})` split at place which has `}` before it (which means split after `}`)
- `(?=\\{)` split at place which has `{` after it (which means split before `{`)

But to be honest `split` or even `regex` may not be tool you are looking for. Try to think of building your own parser/state machine instead.

Comment: as a side note, not related as the question was for java : this expression is not necessarilly supported by all regexp implementation. javascript doesn't support look-behind for example